# "A partnered with B" or "A partnered B" which is correct?

Tags: prepositions

Which of the two options is correct?  Can we do without 'with' in the following sentence?

A partnered with B. 
A partnered B.

Comment: They can both be correct, but you have not indicated what it is you actually mean to say, so it is impossible to say.

Comment: Actually, a bank has partnered with an NGO for its financial inclusion programme.  I wrote 'the bank has partnered with an NGO....".  However, someone 'corrected this sentence' by omitting 'with'.  Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are correct:

> A partnered with B.
>
> A partnered B with C.

However,

> A partnered B.

Leaves us wondering what B got partnered with.  That is unless B actually represents more then one individual.  Like so:

> Sam partnered his kids.  He paired the boys with the girls.